# How to make unique id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I want to make a unique id is like this :

| id | prefix | uniqueid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pm | pm-1 |
| 2 | ad | ad-1 |

The problem is
If i want to add some data where have prefix "ad"
the result must

| id | prefix | uniqueid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pm | pm-1 |
| 2 | ad | ad-1 |
| 3 | ad | ad-2 |

So the result must ad-2, ad-3 , ad-4 and go on
if we add pm so the result must pm-2, pm-3 and go on

I trying to make "table helper" to me but it will be too much table

There's any idea to solve this ?
I use postgres and node js ~

Comment: Why don't use real `id` as a suffix (values would be `ad-2` and `ad-3`)? If it's not possible, you need to select the highest `ad-` record (ordered desc), add +1 to suffix and create `uniqueid` value (I don't  know postgresql, so just a manual how to).

Comment: To add to the comment above, an easier method would be to just do `SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM Table WHERE prefix = 'ad' GROUP BY prefix` to get the next value. But, this seems very impractical and it will probably get slower and slower as more entries get added to the database. If possible I would figure out a way to just use the id column since it's already unique.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object with prefix as key for latest id.

```js
const
    add = (ids => prefix => `${prefix}-${ids[prefix] = (ids[prefix] || 0) + 1}`)
          ({});
    
console.log(add('ad'));
console.log(add('ad'));
console.log(add('pm'));
console.log(add('pm'));
console.log(add('ad'));
```